# Sequelize uses old table name even after changing table name in sequelize migration

Tags: migration, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have updated my table name (from 'StaffMembers' to 'staff' )before running sequelize migration and created a table in postgres db with new name successfully. but when i try to insert a user sequelize still refer old tabel name.

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "StaffMembers" ("id","firstName","lastName","email","password
```

I expect updated table name in "INSERT INTO" command i.e "staff" instead of "StaffMember"

Comment: Got code to share? I suspect you need to update the field in your model -- but without seeing anything you're working with just guessing

Answer (score 0):

**Issue must be** in your model definition

```
sequelize.define(
  'StaffMembers', // <------- Check in your model definition
  {
    ...
  }
);
```

---

**Solution:**

```
sequelize.define(
  'staff', // <------- Change that line to this
  {
    ...
  }
);
```

Comment: that's what i did but its not working. Sequelize still uses "Staffmembers" as model name during execution even after changing model name in model /migration file